# Can't install pysc2

Tags: macos, python-3.x

I want to install `pysc2` by using the command `pip3 install pysc2` from this [link](http://chris-chris.ai/2017/08/30/pysc2-tutorial1/) but terminal shows the following error

```
src/scrap.c:27:10: fatal error: 'SDL.h' file not found
  #include "SDL.h"
1 error generated.
    error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1
```

how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this:
`brew install sdl sdl_image sdl_mixer sdl_ttf portmidi`

I mean you can try reinstalling the sdl if the error is about the sdl.